# Не удаляется текстовый файл Qt

Tags: qt, visual-studio, файлы, qtcreator

Текстовый файл file.txt лежит в той же папке где и файл .pro и все остальные файл проекта. Не могу удалить его программно

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFile>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QFile::remove("file.txt");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Так же создавал файл ресурсов, клал туда file.txt и писал `QFile::remove(":/file.txt");`
или указывал абсолютный путь к файлу - всё равно не удаляет

IDE QtCreator. В Visual Studio всё удаляет нормально

Comment: При сборке исполняемые файлы обычно кладутся в отдельный каталог. Относительный путь будет браться по каталогу исполняемого файла. Что касается абсолютного пути, скорее всего он просто указан неверно либо содержит русские символы.

Comment: текущий каталог IDE может назначать по своему разумению, если вам нужен каталог с exe, то его надо делать из argv[0] с помощью QFileInfo

Comment: относительные пути берутся не относительно расположения исполняемого файла или проекта, а относительно текущего каталога, из которого запускается программа... узнать его можно, например в `QDir::currentPath()`. А указать, например, в настройках IDE... из ресурсов «удалить» файл само собой невозможно, а что касается абсолютного пути — ищи ошибку: или неверное количество слешей, или проблемы с кодировкой...

Comment: Qt нормально обрабатывает русские символы.

Answer (score 0):

А вы уверены, что приложение исполняется в папке проекта, а не директории для сборки?

```
qDebug() << QDir::currentPath();
```